# Better LUT directions for Canon dSLR?

Tags: dslr, color-correction

A year ago I came across a web page describing how to set up a better “pro use” LUT on the camera, that would get better shadow detail recorded.  This was a LUT used in more professional situations and is (as I recall) known to Adobe Premiere already.  I understand that this will make watching the as-saved camera files look bad, and it needs the corresponding LUT selected in Premiere.

I can't find that again now.  Can someone point me to what I need?  The web page featured video stills of chickens. I have a Canon 70D camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this must have been “Cinestyle” by Technicolor, whose home is [this page at the Technicolor web site](http://www.technicolor.com/en/solutions-services/cinestyle).  The chicken instructions was probably [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxQN0Exv9Sg)

Answer (score 1):

The CineStyle LUT JDlugosz mentioned is one. Another popular one is the [ProLost Flat Picture Style](https://prolost.com/blog/2012/4/10/prolost-flat.html). This one just involves adjusting the camera settings. I don't know if Premiere Pro supports it directly (it's mainly just a contrast adjustment), but I do know that Stu Maschwitz (who's blog is linked above) has worked with Adobe in the past, so it wouldn't surprise me if it did.